# How to store settings on iPhone immediately?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, ios4, nsuserdefaults

Is it possible to store settings on the iPhone immediately? The apps on iOS 4+ don't close on exit, and if I press 'Stop process' in Xcode settings are not saved? How to save them?

```
- (void)compLoad {
    compTotal = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey: @"compTotal"];
    compCount = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey: @"compCount"];
    compShow = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey: @"compShow"];
}

- (void)compSave {
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger: compTotal forKey: @"compTotal"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger: compCount forKey: @"compCount"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool: compShow forKey: @"compShow"];
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];**

> synchronize - this method is automatically invoked at periodic
>   intervals, use this method only if you cannot wait for the automatic
>   synchronization (for example, if your application is about to exit) or
>   if you want to update the user defaults to what is on disk even though
>   you have not made any changes.

Answer (score 6):

According to the documentation, the following call will persist any outstanding modifications. To check if this has been successful, check the return value of this call. A value of YES indicates success.

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Comment: can you give more info on how it is failing? your code for setting and getting the user default values might help?

Answer (score 3):

Call your `compSave` in your `AppDelegate`

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application 
{
    // Call your compSave here to force saving before app is going to the background
}
```

also

```
- (void)compSave 
{
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger: compTotal forKey: @"compTotal"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger: compCount forKey: @"compCount"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool: compShow forKey: @"compShow"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
```

Comment: Did you call your `compSave` in the AppDelegate method I mentioned above?

Comment: I call it after every variables change.

Answer (score 2):

Simply call `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];`. But usually you do *not* need to that: iOS will save once your app goes into background and also on a few other occasions. Calling `synchronize` too often is a considered to be a Bad Thing(tm).

Comment: Is data is important - it's good thing) Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Since `synchronize` is the correct solution (I know for sure, I've used NSUserDefaults in several project over the past years) your problem must be elsewhere. Maybe you overwrite your settings somewhere? For example, if you would accidentally call `compSave` before `compLoad` on app start, you'd get "empty" values again. Set a breakpoint on `compSave` and on `compLoad` and have a look which one gets called first when you start your app.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `synchronize` method.

**Update**: you should consider registering your defaults, like it suggests in the [Preferences and Settings Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/AccessingPreferenceValues/AccessingPreferenceValues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000059i-CH3-SW1):

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
   // Register the preference defaults early.
   NSDictionary *appDefaults = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:@"CacheDataAgressively"];
   [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:appDefaults];

   // Other initialization...
}
```

Also, from this guide ("Synchronizing and Detecting Preference Changes"), regarding syncing:

> To detect when changes to a preference value occur, apps can also register for the notification NSUserDefaultsDidChangeNotification. The shared NSUserDefaults object sends this notification to your app whenever it detects a change to a preference located in one of the persistent domains. You can use this notification to respond to changes that might impact your user interface. For example, you could use it to detect changes to the user’s preferred language and update your app content appropriately.

Pretty sure you still need to use `synchronize` if you want to re-read settings directly.